# SVG -> getBBox fails but only half the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to use the getBBox method to get the width of a text element inside an SVG render, BUT for some odd reason it only works half the time, the other half it fails..

Here's my JS code I'm using for that:

```
console.log(iElement.find('.yLabel2:eq(2)')[0].getBBox());
var passWidth = numberTitle2.node().getBBox().width;
```

So half the time it will log `[object SVGRect]` and set passWidth to the width, that's awesome. BUT the other times it logs `[object Exception]`, doesn't log the width, and breaks the rest of the JavaScript following it.

Inside the Exception object there's `name: "NS_ERROR_FAILURE"` and `result: 2147500037`

Any ideas on how to get this to work smoothly or a better way to get the width of an svg element?

Comment: Are you sure you are successfully accessing a valid element?

Comment: @AmeliaBR I'm pretty sure or else it wouldn't work at all. It's being very buggy for some reason..

Comment: What are you using it for?  Would [`getComputedTextLength()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#__svg__SVGTextContentElement__getComputedTextLength) work?  That should provide valid values even if the text element has not been added to the document yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails in Firefox if the text is not rendered. E.g. it is display:none or you've not attached it to the document.

Comment: Is there any way to wait for render to complete? It seems to be failing only half the time. Also you brought up a good point, in chrome it logs 0 for all getBBox values... Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There's an onload event fired on `<svg>` elements you can hook into.

Comment: Related question on difference between browsers:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44438215/svg-getbbox-function-returns-zero-in-firefox-edge-but-not-in-chrome