# SVG getBBox function returns zero in FireFox & Edge (but not in Chrome)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, d3.js, svg

I have an svg element (created with D3).

while in chrome the "getBBox" function works fabulously, it fails in fireFox and Edge. Thought I saw this discussion in couple of places(e.g. [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=612118), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39123010/getbbox-height-returns-0-for-an-svg-path-in-firefox-and-safari-browser)) none of them yielded a clear answer.

This doesn't work either - getBoundingClientRect()
And my element is not underneath  (i saw that it might cause issues).

Thanks alot!

Comment: Is the svg element attached to a document? Is it something that's rendered i.e. a rect rather than a clipPath? You're really going to have to provide an example, otherwise we're just guessing here.

Comment: @RobertLongson Not related to the question, but I just found out, trying to show to OP that getBBox works in firefox, that the MDN [page for getBBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) is missing... do you have any information regarding this?

Comment: I guess nobody has written it. You could always create an account and create an example yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found what was wrong.

Chrome can handle "g" elements with "display : none". but Firefox and edge treat it as "non-existing/zero dimensions".

sorry for the fuss.

Comment: ** I used visibility instead.